# How can we Limit the messages need to be send JMS Queue Tibco

Tags: tibco-ems, tibco-business-works

I need to limit only 5 response messages to be send per second on jms send queue Activity.

Comment: The JMS specification makes no provision for such limits so this would have to be enforced by a provider-specific mechanism. Therefore, I'm removing the `jms` tag.

Answer (score 2):

There is no functionality to limit consumption on TIBCO EMS (Enterprise Messaging Service) broker/product (versions: from 8 to 10.2).

There is possibility to set maximal depth of queue (property: 'maxmsgs'), but this settings prevent to push to many messages by the producer (no time related).

This type of functionality probably needs to be implemented on application/client side.